# I Need to make a script for submit buttton tag (its from native ad platform not google or facebook)

Tags: javascript, php, onclick, tags

i need help making a code to fire a custom pixel code for Native Adv platform after form submit so i can track the converstions
im using html landing page with Submitform Button
I have the pixel code but no idea how to put the code on the submit button function or how to make the script

```
<script>
(
   function(E,n,G,A,g,Y,a){
    E['EngLandingObject'] = g;
    E[g] = E[g] ||
    function(){
     (E[g].q=E[g].q||[]).push(arguments)
    },
    E[g].l=1*new Date();
    Y=n.createElement(G),
    a=n.getElementsByTagName(G)[0];
    Y.async=1;Y.src=A;
    a.parentNode.insertBefore(Y,a)
  }
)(window,document,'script','//widget.engageya.com/eng_landing.js','__engLanding');__engLanding('createPixel',{pixelid:203398,dtms:0});
</script>
///this is the script pixel code

<div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div>
  <div class="form-element cta">
    <input onclick="submitLandingActionForm();return false" type="submit" class="button " value="سجل واكشف السر" id="" >
 </div>
///and this is the onclick submit button
```

Comment: From the look of that code it should create the pixel when the page loads. It works just like the Google Analytics script where it creates a new script tag and some other things after the document loads.

Comment: its pixel code for the thank you page , but they told me i can put it in the submit button can i use google tag manager for this ?